# Ambari - Hive view F080 Error

Tags: hadoop, hive, ambari

I've installed HDP 2.2.0 on a 3 machine cluster running CentOS6 with the help of Ambari, and got no errors during the install process. I then installed the Hive view, as described [here](http://hortonworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/AmbariUserViewsTechPreview_v1.pdf), and the necessary Tez view, but whenever I try to use the view for a query (even a simple SHOW TABLES;), I get this error:

```
 F080 Error in creation /user/zenuser/hive/jobs/hive-job-7-2015-07-15_10-32...
```

I've found nothing thus far, and I don't know where more precise logs might be stored. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following as the super user (hdfs):

> bin/hadoop dfs -mkdir /user/zenuser/
>
> bin/hadoop dfs -chown zenuser /user/zenuser/

Answer (score 1):

The problem came from file permissions. One easy step in resolving this would be to install first the HDFS view, and make sure the Ambari user you're using has all the necessary privileges to write in HDFS.

For more info, read [this](http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/ambari-hive-view-f080-error/#post-74246) link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the property `hive.server2.enable.doAs` to `false`. Refer the [blog](http://big-analytics.blogspot.com.au/2015/11/creating-ambari-hive-views-in-ibm-open.html) for more details